# Python stops working on Windows when calling layer.GetFeatureCount() of OGR

Tags: python, gdal, ogr

My question concerns `OGR` in `Python3` on `Windows`. So I've installed `gdal` from the [wheel file](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs), and I started playing with `OGR` functions, but there's a problem I'm encountering that I can't understand. If `GetFeatureCount()` is called on a layer that was opened in a separate file Python stops working, but not if all my code is in the same script (reading & get count of features).

The code below works:

```py
from osgeo import ogr

filename = '<path>'
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")
datasource = driver.Open(filename)
layer = datasource.GetLayer()
print('Features count:', layer.GetFeatureCount())
```

But if I move the opening of the shapefile's layer to a separate file, it doesn't work anymore (Python stops working somehow):

```py
class IO:
    @staticmethod
    def read_vector(filename):
        # load vector
        driver = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")
        datasource = driver.Open(filename)
        layer = datasource.GetLayer()

        return layer
```

And it called from this file:

```py
from gdal_io import IO


filename =  '<path>'
layer = IO.read_vector(filename)
print('Features count:', layer.GetFeatureCount())
```

Is something necessary after reading the shapefile vector with `OGR`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have been bitten by a well known [GDAL/OGR Python "gotcha"](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/PythonGotchas#Pythoncrashesifyouuseanobjectafterdeletinganobjectithasarelationshipwith).

**Issue**: Your datasource reference has gone out of scope (it's only referenced in the static method) and has orphaned your layer object which causes a crash.

**Note**: This isn't because you've opened the datasource from a class in an imported module, you could reproduce by simply defining a function in your main script that opens a datasource, gets a layer and returns the layer only. Or even by using something like `layer = ogr.Open(filename).GetLayer()`. Either way, the datasource gets dereferenced and python will crash if you try to use the orphaned layer object.

**Solution**: Return the datasource not the layer. Or use [fiona](https://github.com/Toblerity/Fiona), a much more pythonic interface to OGR.